# How to redirect cart page from checkout onepage when product out of stock ?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, onepage-checkout, out-of-stock

I add to cart p1 product when I come checkout onepage that time If another customer buy p1 product and product is out of stock and when I click to continue button as register it is redirecting checkout cart page because of product is `out of stock`. So where is `checkout/cart` redirected code in core files when I stay on `checkout/onepage` and click continue and product out of stock ?

Comment: are you want to redirect user after they register/login and added product is out of stock

Comment: No,If I on checkout/onepage and stay on first step and If product is out of stock and when check regsiter radio button and click continue button I automatically redirect cart page But I want to find where is checkout/cart redirect code when I click continue button ?